# Reported version number of aspnet is unexpected

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, visual-studio, iis-express

I am implementing an MVC 5 website in C# (VS 2013 update 4) and the build setting is targeting .NET framework version 4.5. However when I load the page, I see the following header entry:

X-AspNet-Version:4.0.30319

Why is the website running under .NET 4.0xxxx despite the compile setting is pointing to .NET 4.5? Any ideas?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> That is not the actual .NET framework version. It is the version of the CLR.
>
> From .NET 4 up to 4.5.2 it is version 4. Between 2.0 and 3.5 it was version 2.0.
>
> That is also the reason that in your application pool configuration you can only choose .NET 2 or 4.
>
> See MSDN: .NET Framework Versions and Dependencies on this matter.

https://stackoverflow.com/a/25632090/511418